# Android L (5.x) Turn ON/OFF "Mobile Data" programmatically

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I need to Turn ON/OFF Mobile data programmatically. Below code is not working for 5.x. Can you please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
        final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
        final Field connectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
        connectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object connectivityManager = connectivityManagerField.get(conman);
        final Class connectivityManagerClass =  Class.forName(connectivityManager.getClass().getName());
        final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = connectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(connectivityManager, enabled);    }
```

> 03-30 12:42:29.466: W/System.err(5966):
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setMobileDataEnabled [boolean] 03-30
>   12:42:29.466: W/System.err(5966):     at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664) 03-30 12:42:29.466:
>   W/System.err(5966):   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:626)

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setMobileDataEnabled [boolean] @ below line.

> final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod =
>   connectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled",
>   Boolean.TYPE);

Comment: post the log cat here

Comment: possible duplicate of [The setMobileDataEnabled method is no longer callable as of Android L and later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539445/the-setmobiledataenabled-method-is-no-longer-callable-as-of-android-l-and-later)

Answer (score 5):

> It seems like the **setMobileDataEnabled** method no longer exists in
>   **ConnectivityManager** and this functionality was moved to
>   **TelephonyManager** with two methods getDataEnabled and setDataEnabled.

```
public void setMobileDataState(boolean mobileDataEnabled)
{
    try
    {
        TelephonyManager telephonyService = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = telephonyService.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setDataEnabled", boolean.class);

        if (null != setMobileDataEnabledMethod)
        {
            setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(telephonyService, mobileDataEnabled);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error setting mobile data state", ex);
    }
}

public boolean getMobileDataState()
{
    try
    {
        TelephonyManager telephonyService = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        Method getMobileDataEnabledMethod = telephonyService.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getDataEnabled");

        if (null != getMobileDataEnabledMethod)
        {
            boolean mobileDataEnabled = (Boolean) getMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(telephonyService);

            return mobileDataEnabled;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error getting mobile data state", ex);
    }

    return false;
}
```

When executing the code you get a SecurityException stating that Neither user 10089 nor current process has android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE.

A permission **MODIFY_PHONE_STATE** should be added
I got this from [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539445/the-setmobiledataenabled-method-is-no-longer-callable-as-of-android-l-and-later)
Thank you Muzikant

Comment: But Kushal, as per my understanding without root you can't have that permission in your app. Am I right ?

Comment: You need root access for that. so for user apps its not possible. Thanks.

Comment: Third party apps are not allowed to use this permission.

Answer (score 2):

In Android L 5.xx the hidden API **setMobileDataEnabled** method is removed and it can no longer be used. You can verify this in android lolipop source code under /frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/ConnectivityManager.java.

If you still insist to perform it, you can use code snippet answered by Kushal but  **getDataEnabled** is a system api, which normal user applications cant access. There is also one more system api available **setDataEnabled** under TelephonyManager. (/frameworks/base/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java)

```
/** @hide */
@SystemApi
public void setDataEnabled(boolean enable) {
 setDataEnabled(SubscriptionManager.getDefaultDataSubId(), enable);
}
```

It also needs the permission "android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" which will work only on rooted devices.

Comment: I get a `Cannot resolve method getDefaultDataSubId` error

Comment: How did you used the api? I hope you know how to access a hidden api.

Comment: I've seen that recently (after a certain version) Google made accessing those hidden methods not possible anymore.

Comment: It is possible to access hidden methods, for this you need to modify the android.jar that you use to compile, removing the @hide.

Answer (score 0):

Quick response, it is not possible to enable/disable mobile data by programming as it is possible with bluetooth.

Starting from version 23 of android, data protection begins to be highly valued and also the protection that an application activates or disables something on the phone, for this reason the permissions are implemented, taking this into account

Starting from this, google proposes that you encourage the user to do this action, giving him context and why he needs to have it activated.

**Redirect the user to activate the data**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_USAGE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Redirect the user to activate gps**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Request enable Bluetooth**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```