# Programmatically enabling Mobile data in Android

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to enable mobile data programmatically in Android? I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555366/enable-disable-data-connection-in-android-programmatically) but it is giving following exception:

```
10-06 11:18:14.939: W/System.err(26103): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setMobileDataEnabled [boolean]
10-06 11:18:14.987: W/System.err(26103):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
10-06 11:18:15.032: W/System.err(26103):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:626)
10-06 11:18:15.082: W/System.err(26103):    at com.example.channelbonding.Bonding.setMobileDataEnabled(Bonding.java:344)
10-06 11:18:15.127: W/System.err(26103):    at com.example.channelbonding.Bonding.access$0(Bonding.java:335)
10-06 11:18:15.172: W/System.err(26103):    at com.example.channelbonding.Bonding$1.onClick(Bonding.java:193)
10-06 11:18:15.216: W/System.err(26103):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
10-06 11:18:15.262: W/System.err(26103):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
10-06 11:18:15.308: W/System.err(26103):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-06 11:18:15.352: W/System.err(26103):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-06 11:18:15.393: W/System.err(26103):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-06 11:18:15.441: W/System.err(26103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310)
10-06 11:18:15.481: W/System.err(26103):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-06 11:18:15.525: W/System.err(26103):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-06 11:18:15.575: W/System.err(26103):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
10-06 11:18:15.619: W/System.err(26103):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397919/disable-enabling-mobile-data-programatically-in-android) I read that it is not possible to enable Mobile data.

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340150/android-l-5-x-turn-on-off-mobile-data-programmatically) but it also didn't worked.

How can I enable mobile data in my Android app?

Comment: what are the values you are passing in setMobileDataEnabled () and setMobileDataEnabled has been removed in Android L

Comment: I am passing  boolean true

Comment: Please include the version of android you are gonna try. It varies with API level

Comment: @PaulSen i have edited my comment, setMobileDataEnabled has been removed in Android L

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32817615/1105277