# Toggle mobile data app on Android lollipop

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop

I see the following posted but from a user standpoint I am looking for an app or instructions to toggle data. Thanks.

[The setMobileDataEnabled method is no longer callable as of Android L and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539445/the-setmobiledataenabled-method-is-no-longer-callable-as-of-android-l-and-later/27011670#27011670)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the post you linked do you have root access to the phone? There aren't any other workarounds that I know of. It seems as though this was an intentional change. If you are an XDA member there is this free version supplied that works well on most devices (see link for list).

http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-toggle-data-5-0-widget-to-toggle-t2937936

Comment: I had see this back in Jan. Unfortunately I don't want to root.