# How can I turn off/on 3G/4G/Data programmatically on Android 5.0?

Tags: android, 3g, 4g

Why does this code not work on android **5.0** ?

I testing on android **4.3**, working but on android **5.0** not working.

please help me.

```js
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
     final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     final Class<?> conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
     final java.lang.reflect.Field connectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
     connectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
     final Object connectivityManager = connectivityManagerField.get(conman);
     final Class<?> connectivityManagerClass =  Class.forName(connectivityManager.getClass().getName());
     final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = connectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
     setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

     setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(connectivityManager, enabled);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has called off their API for data on/off pragmatically.
You can check the issue filed on [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=130608).

If you want to know some more details long answer is on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539445/the-setmobiledataenabled-method-is-no-longer-callable-as-of-android-l-and-later) where detailed discussion is there

and if you find this helpful accept this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

It was possible before lollipop using reflection. It is not possible any more.

Comment: What to do now? please help me because need to turn on data in android **5.0**.

Comment: There is nothing you can do my friend. They only allow this in system apps now.

Comment: how ,if device was rooted?

Comment: If your device is rooted you can run a linux script. System apps are those that come pre installed on a device. The ones that can't be uninstalled.