# Can I force android to recheck connection if it's lost?

Tags: android

Can I from my application force android to reconnect to cellular network immediately?
If yes how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the functionality as of `Android 5` has been moved to system apps only. [How to enable mobile data on/off programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817552/how-to-enable-mobile-data-on-off-programmatically/32817693)

But you can still register a listener for network changes.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/reading-network-state

When you get the `onLost()` event you can start a `Wireless Setting Activity` so the user can do it manually.

```
        //As seen in the link above.
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
```

This will be a common occurrence so get use to it. For example you can `createBond()` for a `Bluetooth` device, but you can't `removeBond()` anymore. Thus you have to send the user to the `Bluetooth` setting activity for the user to
"forget" about the device.