# programmatically enable mobile data Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, mobile

I want to automatically on mobile data when Activity get created I have tried almost all the things in this question

[The setMobileDataEnabled method is no longer callable as of Android L and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539445/the-setmobiledataenabled-method-is-no-longer-callable-as-of-android-l-and-later)

but no success.

Comment: this is for you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539445/the-setmobiledataenabled-method-is-no-longer-callable-as-of-android-l-and-later

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The setMobileDataEnabled method is no longer callable as of Android L and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539445/the-setmobiledataenabled-method-is-no-longer-callable-as-of-android-l-and-later)