# How to enable 3G or DataConnection?

Tags: android, 3g, network-connection, data-connections

Actually I want to enable data connection when I enter wrong password on android phone. I used a ConnectivityManager but it is not working fine. 
Here is source code for which I used.

```
ConnectivityManager dataManager;
  dataManager  =(ConnectivityManager)ctxt.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  Method dataMtd = null;
 dataMtd =ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);
dataMtd.setAccessible(true);
dataMtd.invoke(dataManager, true);
```

Comment: I don't think that it should be possible, since data connection is usually paid, and by being able to turn it on without user's will, you are going to spend user's money.

Comment: Thanks @VladMatvienko for your concern. The thing is I took permission on start of application if user allow to access the data connection then it should be possible according to my view.

Comment: I didn't find any permission, that can give you access to this option. Which permission you used?

Comment: I used this permission(below) in manifest... But I think it not may work for Data Connection.. :( <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  @VladMatvienko

Comment: that permission allows you to access internet, and nothing else unfortunately.

Comment: Oh damn.... I don't think there is another way for doing this :( @VladMatvienko

Comment: Right, and there **should be no way to do it**, as it was a way to waste user's money illegally. You should have no way to enable data connection for security reasons.

Comment: Here's what I found. Probably will be usefull to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539445/the-setmobiledataenabled-method-is-no-longer-callable-as-of-android-l-and-later

Comment: Thanks dear @VladMatvienko .. may this work :)