# Apk is disappearing after moving to system parition

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk, android-package-managers

I'm trying to install my apk on system partition. I've rooted device and here are the steps I'm following,

- adb install -d -r <apk_name>
- Now apk gets installed in ***/data/app/<apk_name>/***
- Move all contents present from ***/data/app/<apk_name>*** to **/system/priv-app/<apk_name>**
- Clear the contents within **/data/app/<apk_name>** and reboot the device
- Post reboot not able to find my apk under `adb shell pm list packages | grep <apk_name>`

I'm trying to read and write value to secure setting which is asking my app to be in system partition. When I'm trying to move I'm facing this issue. I could not find something suspicious from logs while installing the apk.

Tried all possible solutions listed here ([Android 5.0/Lollipop: Force rescan of /system/priv-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487750/android-5-0-lollipop-force-rescan-of-system-priv-app)) but none didn't help.

Any help to debug this issue would be really helpful.

Comment: Did you find out a solution for this? It seems to work if I go on a file explorer and copy the contents manually though (or at least sometimes? I don't recall right now. But it worked now. Just not by pushing, for some reason. That one is not working since months ago with me)